# Pandas: new column using data from multiple other file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to add a new column in a pandas dataframe `df`, filled with data that are in multiple other files.

Say my `df` is like this:

```
Sample   Pos
A        5602
A        3069483
B        51948
C        231
```

And I have three files `A_depth-file.txt`, `B_depth-file.txt`, `C_depth-file.txt` like this (showing `A_depth-file.txt`):

```
Pos          Depth
1            31
2            33
3            31
...          ...
5602         52
...          ...
3069483      40
```

The desired output `df` would have a new column `Depth` as follows:

```
Sample   Pos        Depth
A        5602       52
A        3069483    40
B        51948      32
C        231        47
```

I have a method that works but it takes about 20 minutes to fill a `df` with 712 lines, searching files of ~4 million lines (=positions). Would anyone know a **better/faster way** to do this?

The code I am using now is:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

with open("mydf.txt") as f:
    next(f)
    List=[]
    for line in f:
        df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(line), header=None)
        df.rename(columns = {df.columns[1]: "Pos"}, inplace=True)
        f2basename = df.iloc[:, 0].values[0]
        f2 = f2basename + "_depth-file.txt"
        df2 = pd.read_csv(f2, sep='\t')
        df = pd.merge(df, df2, on="Pos", how="left")
        List.append(df)
df = pd.concat(List, sort=False)
```

`with open("mydf.txt") as f:` to open the file to which I wish to add data

`next(f)` to pass the header

`List=[]` to create a new empty array called `List`

`for line in f:` to go over `mydf.txt` line by line and reading them with `df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(line), header=None)`

`df.rename(columns = {df.columns[1]: "Pos"}, inplace=True)` to rename lost header name for `Pos` column, used later when merging line with associated file `f2`

`f2basename = df.iloc[:, 0].values[0]` getting basename of associated file `f2` based on 1st column of `mydf.txt`

`f2 = f2basename + "_depth-file.txt"`to get full associated file `f2` name

`df2 = pd.read_csv(f2, sep='\t')` to read file `f2`

`df = pd.merge(df, df2, on="Pos", how="left")`to merge the two files on column `Pos`, essentially adding `Depth` column to `mydf.txt`

`List.append(df)`adding modified line to the array `List`

`df = pd.concat(List, sort=False)` to concatenate elements of the `List` array into a dataframe `df`

---

#### **Additional NOTES**

In reality, I may need to search not only three files but several hundreds.

Comment: This may be better suited to Code Review.

Comment: @JimEisenberg Considering it's a short piece of code with a specific problem statement (it's way too slow), I see no problem with leaving it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test the execution time, but should be faster if you read your `'mydf.txt'` file in a dataframe too using `read_csv` and then use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [groupby apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html).

If you know in advance that you have 3 samples and 3 relative files storing the depth, you can make a dictionary to read and store the three respective dataframes in advance and use them when needed.

```
df = pd.read_csv('mydf.txt', sep='\s+')
files = {basename : pd.read_csv(basename +  "_depth-file.txt", sep='\s+') for basename in ['A', 'B', 'C']}

res = df.groupby('Sample').apply(lambda x : pd.merge(x, files[x.name], on="Pos", how="left"))
```

The final `res` would look like:

```
         Sample      Pos  Depth
Sample                         
A      0      A     5602   52.0
       1      A  3069483   40.0
B      0      B    51948    NaN
C      0      C      231    NaN
```

There are `NaN` values because I am using the sample provided and I don't have files for B and C (I used a copy of A), so values are missing. Provided that your files contain a `'Depth'` for each `'Pos'` you should not get any `NaN`.

To get rid of the multiindex made by `groupby` you can do:

```
res.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

and `res` becomes:

```
  Sample      Pos  Depth
0      A     5602   52.0
1      A  3069483   40.0
2      B    51948    NaN
3      C      231    NaN
```

#### EDIT after comments

Since you have a lot of files, you can use the following solution: same idea, but it does not require to read all the files in advance. Each file will be read when needed.

```
def merging_depth(x):
    td = pd.read_csv(x.name + "_depth-file.txt", sep='\s+')
    return pd.merge(x, td, on="Pos", how="left")

res = df.groupby('Sample').apply(merging_depth)
```

The result is the same.

Comment: Thanks for this! I did not say in my post, but in my current analysis, I have ~200 samples, therefore ~200 files from which to search data. Do you think your method will still work and be more efficient than my method with such a number of dataframes to store in memory?

Comment: If your PC has enough memory, yes. Will be faster having the dataframes in memory rather than read each one many times.

Comment: Amazing! Took about 4 minutes instead of 20. I am new to python and I sure need to learn more about the apply function.